# FFMPEG add audio to a video but clip it to the video length

Tags: video, audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a video from an image sequence and add audio with FFMPEG

The frame sequence is only 25 frames long but the audio is several minutes. I want FFMPEG to clip the audio to the length of the frame sequence.

This is the command I have tried:

```
ffmpeg -i input_images%04d.jpg -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec mjpeg -qmin 1 -qmax 1 -r 25 -i audio_file.mp3 -ar 22050 -ab 192k -aframes 25 output.mov
```

This results in a video with the first image sequence but the full length audio. -aframes is ignored. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the FFmpeg documentation:

```
ffmpeg -i in%04d.jpg -i in.mp3 -shortest out.mov
```

The `-shortest` option finishes encoding when the shortest input stream ends.

When you're merging video and audio files, you can also copy the bitstreams to avoid encoding:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.m4a -c copy -map 0:v -map 1:a output.mp4
```